# Keep selected language between different pages

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I have a simple html website with different html pages. I'm using [i18n](https://www.i18next.com/) translation in javascript.
How can I keep the selected language between different pages?

```
<li class="hidden">
        <a href="index.html"></a>
</li>
<li>
        <a href="quemsomos.html" data-i18n="menu_whoweare">Quem Somos</a>
</li>
```

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: you can use cookie?